# knockout foreach nested in a with

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, foreach, with-statement

I want to bind a simple structure with ko but I am getting an exception during binding. 
My VM looks like this:

```js
function VM() {
    this["longNameObjId1"] = new Object();
    this["longNameObjId1"].records = ko.observableArray();

    var obj1 = new Object();
    obj1.L1 = "a";
    obj1.L2 = "b";
    obj1.L3 = "c";
    this["longNameObjId1"].records.push(obj1);

    var obj2 = new Object();
    obj2.L1 = "A";
    obj2.L2 = "B";
    obj2.L3 = "C";

    this["longNameObjId1"].records.push(obj2)            
}
```

I am trying to iterate through all the objects in the *records* array of the longNameObjId1 property and put them in a table. I do need to have some control over the changing of the records array, so I started with wrapping the foreach flow control, like this:

```js
ko.bindingHandlers.dynCollection = {
    init: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel, context){                
        ko.bindingHandlers.foreach.init(element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel, context);
    },
    update: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel, context) {                
        ko.bindingHandlers.foreach.update(element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel, context);                
    }
};
```

Nothing fancy. On the view side, I thought this should do it:

```html
<!-- ko with: longNameObjId1 -->
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th style="width: 33%">L1</th>
            <th style="width: 25%">L2</th>
            <th style="width: 25%">L3</th>
            <th style="width: 17%"></th>
            <th></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="test_tBody" data-bind="dynCollection: records">
        <tr>
            <td id="test_td1" data-bind="text: L1"></td>
            <td id="test_td2" data-bind="text: L2"></td>
            <td id="test_td3" data-bind="text: L3"></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
<!-- /ko -->
```

At run time I can see the table in the browser, with the expected data. The problem that I am having is the fact that I receive an exception that goes like this:

```
Error: Unable to parse bindings.
Message: ReferenceError: L1 is not defined;
Bindings value: text: L1
```

I would happily ignore the error since I can see my data in the browser, but the problem is the fact that the *records* array is not really binded: for instance calling *push()* from the console after the table is displayed (and the error ignored) does not trigger the *dynCollection.update()* function.

Can somebody please point out where my error is, or perhaps a better way of mapping the *records* array?

I am using knockout 2.2.1 with FF 20.0 on a Windows Server 2008 R2 SP1.

If you need more details, please let me know.
Thanks,
Flo.

**Update** 
Amongst some of the things that I tried was using the context property *$data* like this:

```
<td id="test_td1" data-bind="text: $data.L1"></td>
```

This turned out a rather unexpected behavior: the error no longer manifested itself, but nor did my table: I got an empty table in my page, but no error. There has to be something I definitely do not understand about bindings. I would appreciate if somebody can shed some light on this particular behavior. Thanks.

Comment: dynCollection is totally redundant, why not use foreach binding directly?

Comment: I need to catch all changes to this collection, regardless if it is a user action or a server notification and perform additional tasks on the client side. Wrapping the __foreach__ binding was just the first step.

Comment: Ok, just one thought, if its logic only and no UI its better fitted as a observable extender. custom handlers are for VM <> UI bindings

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I'll check the observable extenders, as I will also have lots of data that will go into d3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add `return` before your `foreach.init` subcall:

```
init: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel, context){                
    return ko.bindingHandlers.foreach.init(element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel, context);
},
```

This stops table row templating while `records` is not initialized.

Comment: To clarify, what this does is return { controlsDescendantBindings: true } which will make KO understand that the html rendered by the binding should not be bound by the current context but rather by the context defined by the binding handler